# Is there a way to determine if execCommand('bold') is being executed right now?

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a simple JavaScript text editor with a bold function. I am using `execCommand('bold')` for this. For the bold-icon in the toolbar I have to check if I am writing bold right now. I was thinking of a boolean variable which is being set everytime I execute the command, but this is not possible since text can be selected and so on.

So is there a way to determine if execCommand('bold') is being executed right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [Document.queryCommandState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/queryCommandState) method.

```js
bolder.onclick = e => {
  document.execCommand('bold');
};

inp.onfocus = document.onselectionchange = e =>
  bolder.classList.toggle('active', isWritingBold());

function isWritingBold() {
  return document.queryCommandState('bold');
}
```

```css
#bolder.active::before {
  content: 'un-';
}
```

```html
<button id="bolder">boldify current selection</button>
<div id="inp" contenteditable>edit me and <b>boldify</b> any part of my content</div>
```

Comment: If you delete the current text, press boldify, write some text and remove it with backspace, the button will say boldify. But if you write something again, you realise that bold is still executing. Thats my main problem.

Comment: @Pezcraft there is actually a built-in... Thanks for letting me learn about this ;-)